# sybase - values from one table that aren't on another, on opposite ends of a 3-table join

Tags: sql, sybase, outer-join

Hypothetical situation: I work for a custom sign-making company, and some of our clients have submitted more sign designs than they're currently using. I want to know what signs have never been used.

3 tables involved:

table A - signs for a company

sign_pk(unique) |   company_pk | sign_description
1   --------------------1  ---------------- small
2   --------------------1  ---------------- large
3   --------------------2  ---------------- medium
4   --------------------2  ---------------- jumbo
5   --------------------3  ---------------- banner

table B - company locations

company_pk  | company_location(unique)
1   ------|------   987
1   ------|------   876
2   ------|------   456
2   ------|------   123

table C - signs at locations (it's a bit of a stretch, but each row can have 2 signs, and it's a one to many relationship from company location to signs at locations)

company_location | front_sign | back_sign
987  ------------ 1 ------------     2
987  ------------ 2 ------------     1
876  ------------ 2 ------------     1
456  ------------ 3 ------------     4
123  ------------ 4 ------------     3

So, a.company_pk = b.company_pk and b.company_location = c.company_location. What I want to try and find is how to query and get back that sign_pk 5 isn't at any location. Querying each sign_pk against all of the front_sign and back_sign values is a little impractical, since all the tables have millions of rows. Table a is indexed on sign_pk and company_pk, table b on both fields, and table c only on company locations. The way I'm trying to write it is along the lines of "each sign belongs to a company, so find the signs that are not the front or back sign at any of the locations that belong to the company tied to that sign."

My original plan was:
`Select a.sign_pk

    from a, b, c

    where a.company_pk = b.company_pk

    and b.company_location = c.company_location

    and a.sign_pk *= c.front_sign

    group by a.sign_pk having count(c.front_sign) = 0`

just to do the front sign, and then repeat for the back, but that won't run because c is an inner member of an outer join, and also in an inner join.

This whole thing is fairly convoluted, but if anyone can make sense of it, I'll be your best friend.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT sign_pk
    FROM table_a
   WHERE sign_pk NOT IN
    (   
      SELECT DISTINCT front_sign sign
        FROM table_c
       UNION
      SELECT DISTINCT rear_sign sign
       FROM  table_c
    )
```

Comment: Querying each sign_pk against all of the front_sign and back_sign values is a little impractical, since all the tables have millions of rows, and the front_sign and back_sign columns aren't indexed. That seems like it would lead to two table scans of table c.

Comment: LazyBob, it's going to be difficult to design an efficient solution given the bad design of the hypothetical tables. If you draw the tables you'll see that the relationships form a triangle. The "signs at locations" table should only have 1 sign_pk in it and have a "sign type" column.

Comment: dcp, I think yours is probably the best possible solution given the table structure. I wouldn't bother with the "distinct" *within* the IN clause, it forces unnecessary work onto sybase for no actual improvement.

Answer (score 0):

ANSI outer join is your friend here. *= has dodgy semantics and should be avoided

```
select distinct a.sign_pk, a.company_pk
from a join b on a.company_pk = b.company_pk 
left outer join c on b.company_location = c.company_location 
                  and (a.sign_pk = c.front_sign or a.sign_pk = c.back_sign) 
where c.company_location is null
```

Note that the **where** clause is a filter on the rows returned by the join, so it says "do the joins, but give me only the rows that *didn't* to join to c"

Outer join is almost always faster than NOT EXISTS and NOT IN

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to create a Temp table for the inner join and then outer join that.
But it really depends on the size of your data sets.
Yes, the schema design is flawed, but we can't always fix that!